# efficient canvas refresh with fyne golang

Tags: go, optimization, canvas, fyne

I have the code below, It shows a window, generate an image as raster and then update the window content with it.
However, the setContent method is slow (with it I have 100% of 1 cpu core and almost 0 without).

I wonder if there is anything to do to do what I do here efficiently (modifiying underlaying raster, use gpu in anyway...) . I would like to be able to generate an image with raster and then display it at ~60 fps efficiently.

Any suggestion or other tools to do it better would be appreciated.

```golang
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    w := myApp.NewWindow("Raster")

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
            raster := canvas.NewRasterWithPixels(
                func(_, _, w, h int) color.Color {
                    return color.RGBA{uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                        uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                        uint8(rand.Intn(255)), 0xff}
                })
            w.SetContent(raster)
        }
    }()
    w.SetFullScreen(true)
    // w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(120, 100))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Comment: On my computer, on Windows, it uses around 3% CPU with the loop. Set the content once and use `raster.Refresh()` to prevent what appears to be a memory leak. It will use the same function every time. I don't know much about Fyne but I think OpenGL is entirely abstracted for you.

Comment: after some extra tests, the main loop of my program runs at 60 fps, however the render in the window is ~1 fps . There is 1 of my CPU core that is used at 100%. I guess there is a go thread that is controling some underlaying opengl rendering (software) and it is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the window content is a very expensive call as it has to re-layout all the content and check sizes etc.
Just call raster.Refresh() instead.
You could also cache the raster pixels in your widget so you don’t have to create a new image for every frame to refresh.